# Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory

Tags: spring, mongodb

I was getting error: `Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory`. Here is the full stacktrace:

```
05/07/2018 17:16:03.386 [localhost-startStop-48] ERROR
                                o.s.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(316) - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory
        at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:151) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:157) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:108) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:278) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
```

The contents of ApplicationContext.xml are as follows:

```
<bean id="mongoConfig"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:/config/mongo.properties" />
</bean>

<mongo:db-factory id="dbName" dbname="test" />


<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="#{mongoConfig['mongo.host']}" />
    <property name="port" value="#{mongoConfig['mongo.port']}" />
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg value="#{mongoConfig['mongo.dbName']}" />
</bean>
```

Now I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean] for bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [config/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:668) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:398) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1276) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] ... 49 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.65] at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.65] at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:274) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:437) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1428) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
```

Contents of the pom.xml file are as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.moglix.ecom.search.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>
    <url>http://www.moglix.com</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.moglix.ecom</groupId>
        <artifactId>search</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
        <spring.data.version>5.0.7.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
        <spring.version>5.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <elastic-search.version>1.7.1</elastic-search.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <quartz.version>1.6.1</quartz.version>
        <supercsv.version>2.1.0</supercsv.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.moglix.ecom.search.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.moglix.platform.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> 
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Elastic Search -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>${elastic-search.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thetransactioncompany/cors-filter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Caching Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring caching framework inside this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Support for Ehcache and others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <!-- building -->
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>compile</defaultGoal>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>searchApi</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <!-- plugins -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-clean-config</id>
                            <phase>pre-clean</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <file>user.properties</file>
                                </files>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>initialize-config</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <file>user.properties</file>
                                </files>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                        <additionalProjectnatures>
                            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        </additionalProjectnatures>
                        <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now I am getting following error:

```
06/07/2018 20:56:46.045 [localhost-startStop-80] ERROR
                o.s.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(331) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate com.moglix.ecom.es.api.dao.MongoDao.mongoTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [config/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/context/InvalidPersistentPropertyPath
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1960) [catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate com.moglix.ecom.es.api.dao.MongoDao.mongoTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [config/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/context/InvalidPersistentPropertyPath
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [config/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/context/InvalidPersistentPropertyPath
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/context/InvalidPersistentPropertyPath
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mapping/context/InvalidPersistentPropertyPath
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:119) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:2111) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:222) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:186) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.65]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Stop mixing spring versions. You are mixing jars from 4.1.4 and 5.07.

Comment: I have changes version to 5.0.7 . Now I am getting following error    @M.Deinum

Comment: Don't add additional information as an answer, edit your question!. The exception is pretty clear imho. You don't have the necessary dependencies or are using the wrong classes.

Comment: thx, I have added pom.xml file. Can you please give some hint about which dependency should I add or change version @M.Deinum

Comment: As mentioned stop mixing versions of frameworks. You are mixing spring data versions as well `1.0.2` and `2.0.8` it also appears as if you are using old code with newer frameworks. You are cobling things together, I strongly suggest using the spring framework BOM and spring data framework bom, that way you will at least have consistent versions.

Comment: i have synched all spring projects version. Please help with my current log

Answer (score 0):

M Deinum is correct that this class of error "springs" from mixing spring versions.  I am answering in order to share a specific flavor of mixing that is less than obvious to newbies like me.  I have encountered an error almost identical to this one.  The mixed versions that I did not realize I had were that I had "brought with me" a spring-data-mongodb dependency from another spring (non-boot) project.  M Deinum's answer led me to double check that and find that I needed to switch to spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb.